# How is "width: 100%" computed when I add an element to a table cell dynamically?

Tags: css, backgrid

Backgrid allows editing values in a table, and accomplishes this by putting an `<input type="text">` inside the `<td>`. The input is set to `max-width: 100%` but it still pushes the size of the column out farther in some cases.

For an example, see the grid [on their Examples](http://backgridjs.com/#basic-example) section and click an item in the "Population" column. When it gets the `editor` class, its padding is set to 0, and both the `<td>` and `<input>` have `box-sizing: border-box`, but the width of the column still increases.

So does `width: 100%` not mean 100% of the width of the `<td>` as it is at the time? Or is it just not possible to make this work using CSS only? I could probably use a backbone event to get the size of the td and then set the input to the same size but that sounds a bit hacky.

Comment: Does the `<input>` still have a margin?

Comment: @Blazemonger no, the input has margin, border, and outline all set to zero; you can see the CSS here: http://backgridjs.com/build/build.css (selector ".backgrid td.editor input[type=text]")

Comment: Yeah, I'm not scrolling through all of that. You're more likely to get assistance on SO if you provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) that we can edit ourselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the width of table columns is calculated is not trivial. They try to distribute the available space among the columns in a way that columns with more content gets a bigger share.

If you go and say "the content should be as big as the column" you make that even more complex because you create a ciruclar dependency between content width and column width.

> So does `width: 100%` not mean 100% of the width of the `<td>` as it is at the time?

No. When anything changes, everything is updated. CSS does not keep a history, so it does not know the width of an element at a particular time. So `width: 100%` means that after everything was updated, the input will have the same width as the `<td>`. But that may be different from what it was before the change.

I do not have the perfect solution for your problem, but these are some ideas:

- check the column width before replacing the content using JavaScript (as you already noted in your question)
- Use [fixed table layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout). This way all columns have the same width and will not change based on their content.
- set [`contenteditable`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#contenteditable) on the `<td>` instead of using an input element. This should not impact the columns width — at least not as long as you do not actually edit the content.

Comment: Well it's not the answer I was hoping for but that makes a lot of sense, thanks. Yes I had descended a bit into the circular dependency of setting widths as you mentioned. I was actually considering writing some sort of "table lock" function to take the computed widths, convert them to percentages and apply via `.css('width')`, then set `table-layout: fixed`. However I didn't know about `contenteditable`; that looks very promising.